# Why was William Cage sent to the base?

Tags: plot-explanation, edge-of-tomorrow

At the beginning of the movie Edge of Tomorrow, William Cage (Tom Cruise) was sent to the war base prior to going to fight. What caused him to be sent to the war base?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

At the beginning, he was asked to come to General Brigham's office. The General wanted Cage to show the war from the front ... from where the action was. Then Cage refused and then tried to blackmail the General. Cage thinks he's getting his way as he's walking out the building, but the General is just lining him up for failure as he has the guards take him down with a Taser like device, which knocks Cage out. Cage wakes up to find himself on the tarmac with some gear. Then Master Sergeant Farell picks him up and takes him to the barracks to be with J-Squad. **Because of Cage's blackmail of the General, the General changed Cage's orders.** Instead of going as a Major shooting footage and being the "front man" war corespondent, Cage was now forced to go to the front as a Private Infantryman.

Comment: *"At the beginning, he was asked to come to General Brigham's office."* I think that should read *"At the beginning, he was **told to report** to General Brigham's office."* (same, bit with a military slant) ..and that, either way, is the answer to the question.  He was there because he was told to be there!